# Rails: Rendering a partial to the right div?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, partial, renderpartial

I have a loop in my view that renders many partials: each partial is a simple toggle to perform a save/unsave operation on a record. Each partial toggles the boolean field using javascript then updates itself, and the controller finishes by saying:

```
$ controller
render :partial => "save_unsave_buttons", :locals => {:matching => @matching}, :layout => false

# view    
<div id=<%= "save#{match.id}" -%>>
<%= render :partial => "save_unsave_buttons", :locals => {:matching => match} %>
</div>
```

When the controller renders the save_unsave_buttons partial, it isn't rendering to the right div; it just updates the partial for the first record it finds. How can I ask the controller to render the save_unsave_buttons partial to the div with the right id?

Thanks!

Comment: Being able to see the loop you're talking about would be helpful.

I'm also not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why are your rendering the partial form the controller? We need to see more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at only the little info that you provided for your problem i guess the culprit in the code is the `div` tag.

The `div` tag should be within the partial.

**EDIT**: What your code does is it creates a single `div` with id `save(the first match.id)` and renders the partial within it. If I understood you correctly you need a `div` for each `match`. For that the `div` itself should be within the partial.

So pass the `match.id` to the partial in a `collection`. Your view should be:

```
# view    

<%= render :partial => "save_unsave_buttons", :locals => {:matching => match, :collection => {@match_id => match.id} } %>
```

and in your partial **_sav_unsave_buttons.html.erb**:

```
<% content_tag :div, id => "save#{@match_id}" do %>

     #YOUR CODE GOES HERE!

<% end -%>
```